# Parse Nested YAML into Key Value Pairs with Ruby

Tags: ruby, nested, yaml

I am looking to solve parsing YAML data like this with ruby

```
access_log:
  stored_proc: getsomething
    uses:
      usedin: some breadcrumb
```

I was able to parse into key-pair for (access_log>> stored_proc>> getsomething )
but having issues with flow for(access_log >> uses >> usedin >> some breadcrumb) to have usedin >> some breadcrumb as key value pair. I would appreciate your help

Comment: the complexity of the above problem is re-purposed with different yaml file structure

Comment: the complexity of the above problem is re-purposed with different yaml file structure   e.g  X: A,B,C after using split(","), each of A,B,C are handled separately like A: A1Key:A1Value etc, with following code >> vendor_data1 = YAML.load(File.read('VendorUser.yaml'))
iterate_type = vendor_data1['X']
iterate_values = iterate_type.split(",")
vendor_data_load['B'].each do |key,value| >>only problem is key, value pairs are correct, but it is iterating based on array class generated, in this case it is 3, is there a way to control iteration, if the value of array string is B, only B should |k,v|

Comment: solved the unnecessary iteration for the string item with this  method  def in_array?(array, item)
    item = [item] unless item.is_a?(Array)
    item == array & item
end

Answer (score 1):

Your YAML is malformed. You cannot have key with a value and something else nested under that key

```
# malformed.yml
access_log:
  stored_proc: getsomething
    uses:
      usedin: some breadcrumb

# irb
YAML.load_file 'malformed.yml'
Psych::SyntaxError: (malformed.yml): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 3 column 9
    from (irb):51
```

The correct structure will be

```
access_log:
  stored_proc: getsomething
  uses:
    usedin: some breadcrumb
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is your YAML structure (?):

```
# data.yml
- access_log:
  - stored_proc: getsomething
    uses:
      usedin: some breadcrumb

# file.rb
require 'yaml'

data = YAML.load_file '/Users/seb/Desktop/data.yaml'
p data.first['access_log']                         # [{"stored_proc"=>"getsomething", "uses"=>{"usedin"=>"some breadcrumb"}}]
p data.first['access_log'].first['stored_proc']    # "getsomething"
p data.first['access_log'].first['uses']           # {"usedin"=>"some breadcrumb"}
p data.first['access_log'].first['uses']['usedin'] # "some breadcrumb"
```